# Understanding the asyncronous nature of fetch().then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This is a predominantly theoretical question as I guess I would not use the fetched data  outside of the .then() method.
I was just checking the behaviour of fetch.then() out of curiosity as I like to test and understand the principles of the languages I learn.

As expected

```
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log("myGlobVar in setTimeOut");
console.log(myGlobVar)}, 1000);
```

returns the fetched object, provided I use a delay long enough in setTimeOut (about 40ms in this case)

But I'm curious why the

```
console.log("myGlobVar after for loop");
console.log(myGlobVar); //returns undefined
```

does not work.
My rationale here was that running the loop long enough,  would give enough time to `fetch()` to fetch the data and assign it to `myGlobVar`, which doesn't happen no matter how long it runs.

Actually -counterintuitively- for extremely high numbers in the loop (1000000000) even the

```
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log("myGlobVar in setTimeOut");
console.log(myGlobVar)}, 1000);
```

returns undefined.

```
<script>
  "use strict"
let myGlobVar;
  function loadPeaks() {
  console.log("loadPeaks");
  fetch('soundofChengdu.json')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(peaks => {
    // wavesurfer.load('soundofChengdu.mp3', peaks.data);
    myGlobVar= peaks;
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log({errorIs: e})
    // console.error('error', e);
  });
  }

  loadPeaks();
  console.log("myGlobVar without waiting");
  console.log(myGlobVar); //returns undefined
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log("myGlobVar in setTimeOut"); console.log(myGlobVar)}, 1000); //returns undefined under +-40 ms, works above.

let b;
 console.log("loop running");
  for (let a=0; a<100000000; a++) {
    b=b+a;
  }

console.log("myGlobVar after for loop");
console.log(myGlobVar); //returns undefined

</script>
```

Comment: it's entirely possible that the JavaScript runtime could detect that your loop did nothing useful and just optimized it away. In any case this experiment is not really useful. Asynchronous APIs are about external processes over which the source has no control; the asynchronous operations take as long as they take, and they're unpredictable and inconsistent.

Comment: that loop will run completely, and the code after it, before the `.then(response => {` gets a chance to be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is quite usual, you blocked the event-loop synchronously, no other task or even microtask can be executed in between so your variable is not set.

The second part about `setTimeout()` firing before the request's `Promise` gets resolved is a bit more interesting though, what you've discovered here is the *task prioritization* system.

All tasks don't have the same priority, and browsers are free to execute one kind of task before another.

For instance here, your browser gives more importance to *timer* tasks than to *network* tasks. And for the ones wondering "*but `fetch().then()` is a microtask and should have higher priority*", the returned Promise is resolved in a "normal" task (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566665/3702797) of mine), and that task is subject to the *task prioritization* system.

Answer (score 1):

The code after `loadPeaks()` is synchronously called, meaning that the code will not wait for `loadPeaks()` to finish running and will run completely before `loadPeaks()` finishes.

This is the same for the for loop. Regardless of the iteration count, the for loop will finish before the request finishes. You can test this by adding a `console.log()` statement in your second `then()` call and see when it is printed in relation to the rest of your log statements.

`Promise.then()` on the other hand, waits for the request to finish. In your case, `fetch()` will run first and the `then()` calls will run sequentially, waiting for the previous call to finish before running.

Answer (score 1):

> My rationale here was that running the loop long enough, would give enough time to fetch() to fetch the data and assign it to myGlobVar, which doesn't happen no matter how long it runs.

JavaScript is actually strictly single-threaded, unlike most other languages you're probably familiar with. Instead of having threads running in parallel, it uses an [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) pattern where each operation runs, pushes follow-up operations onto the queue, and then yields back to the loop. I'll quote from the article I just linked to explain how this affects your code (emphasis mine):

> ### "Run-to-Completion"
>
> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed.
>
> This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it **cannot be preempted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates)**. This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it may be stopped at any point by the runtime system to run some other code in another thread.

This explains why the code after the `for` loop never has access to that global variable no matter how high the iteration count is: the event loop is still executing your original function, so none of those promise handlers have had any chance to execute.

@Kaiido's answer for your second question is much better than what I was going to write, so I won't bother. I'll leave the above up just in case a more basic explanation helps.